# Array Sorting Question for News System

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to sort my array files. I have a simple news posting system that stores the content in seperate **.dat** files and then stores them in an array. I numbered the files so that my array can sort them from lowest number to greatest; however, I have run into a small problem. To begin here is some more information on my system so that you can understand it better.

The function that gathers my files is:

```
function getNewsList() {
        $fileList = array();
        // Open the actual directory
        if($handle = opendir(ABSPATH . ADMIN . "data")) {
            // Read all file from the actual directory
            while($file = readdir($handle))  {
                if(!is_dir($file)) {
                    $fileList[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the array.
        return $fileList;
    }
```

On a seperate file is the programming that processes the news post. I didn't post that code for simplicity's sake but I will explain how the files are named. The files are numbered and the part of the post's title is used... for the numbering I get a count of the array and add "1" as an offset. I get the title of the post, encode it to make it file-name-friendly and limit the amount of text so by the end of it all I end up with:

```
// Make the variable that names the file that will contain
  // the post.
  $filename = "00{$newnumrows}_{$snipEncode}";
```

When running **print_r** on the above function I get:

```
Array (
     [0] => 0010_Mira_mi_Soledad.dat
     [1] => 0011_WOah.dat
     [2] => 0012_Sinep.dat
     [3] => 0013_Living_in_Warfa.dat
     [4] => 0014_Hello.dat
     [5] => 001_AS.dat
     [6] => 002_ASASA.dat
     [7] => 003_SSASAS.dat
     ...
     [13] => 009_ASADADASADAFDAF.dat
)
```

And this is how my content is displayed. For some reason according to the array sorting **0010** comes before **001**...? Is there a way I can get my array to sort **001** before **0010**?

Comment: After your first function where you are creating the $fileList[] array, what's it look like if you do... echo "<pre>";print_r($fileList);echo"</pre>"; This should show you the order it's setting the array to. You may have to foreach over this into a new array w/ some sorting routine set up to get it in the order you're looking for.

Comment: I wish the comments section read line breaks.... I tried making it more readable but it comes out like this:
Array (
 [0] => 0010_Mira_mi_Soledad.dat
 [1] => 0011_WOah.dat
 [2] => 0012_Sinep.dat
 [3] => 0013_Living_in_Warfa.dat
 [4] => 0014_Hello.dat
 [5] => 001_AS.dat
 [6] => 002_ASASA.dat
 [7] => 003_SSASAS.dat
 ...
 [13] => 009_ASADADASADAFDAF.dat
)

Comment: @lemonpole: If I understand your question, you want to build an array containing filenames and their creation/modification times and sort it by timestamp?

Comment: I see where you are getting at. That is how it is displayed on the page... so it is reading "0010" before "001".. the error is not with pagination but with how it is being sorted into the array with the first function?

Comment: @lemonpole: What I mean is, what is the real question here?

Comment: @netcoder: no I was just explaining how I was naming my files... I just wanted it to be sorted from the newest files to the latest files which is why I tried numbering the files "00xx_{postname}.dat".. I just thought maybe the pagination was causing the files to be sorted wierd but i'm starting to think maybe the problem is the first function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the filename and extract the prefix number as integer number:

```
// $filename has the format: "00{$newnumrows}_{$snipEncode}"
function generateSortKey($filename)
{
    $separatorPos = stripos($filename, '_');

    $prefix = trim(substr($filename, 0, $separatorPos));
    return intval($prefix);
}
```

Than create an associative array from the list of files, the keys will be used as sortable value later:

```
function toSortableArray($files)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($files as $filename)
    {
        $key = generateSortKey($filename);
        $value = $filename;

        $result[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and at last use [krsort()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php):

```
$list = getNewsList();
$sortableList = toSortableArray($list);

krsort($sortableList);   // after that $sortableList is
                         // sorted by key in descending order now
```

FIX: ksort() => krsort()

Comment: Yes, thank you! Your method achieves exactly what I was looking for. I did change it a bit and changed **ksort()** to **krsort** to sort it from newest to oldest :) thanks so much

Comment: oh, that's right, you want to sort descending ... sorry my mistake ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but I discovered a small problem. Although krsort() did sort it in reverse order, it did not mix well with pagination so it only reversed it on the page it was at but kept it on page 2 of 2. I fixed the problem using **rsort($sortableList, SORT_NUMERIC);**.... sorry for all the edits! :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use natcasesort(array) function of php which will sort an array using a "natural order" algorithm and you will get the desired output

HTH.

:Malay

Comment: `natsort` would have done it, but +1 anyway for simplicity :) If OP wants to sort reverse, then `array_reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with underscore. Always numerical characters get sorted before underscore.

See whether you get the desired result using `sort($your_array, SORT_NUMERIC)`.

For more info, refer [PHP Manual for sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

You may also use `natcasesort()` (as Malay suggested) or `natsort()`. But both maintain index association.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I believe I have the numerical characters before the underscore. I have tried using sort(), natcasesort(), and natsort(), but it still sorts **0010** before **001**.. i'm currently in the process of trying marcel's method maybe that will work

Comment: Try replacing `_` by any character whose ASCII value is less than that of character 0 (i.e. 48).